# world grid is visible in render (how to remove?)

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, image, video, world

I've been trying to find a solution for quite some while and I couldn't find one so I decided to make a post here.
I've been trying to learn motion tracking with blender and I got the track and I attach it to a image object. I then add a background image to the camera and the the image object was moving in front of the background image.
Everything was great until I pressed render and guess what? The world grid was **IN** my render.

Is there a way to have a camera background image and not have the grid on top?
I tried to but the background image in depth: front but then the image object was behind the background image.

Comment: plz share image whats the problem

Comment: Grid can be disabled by going to 3d view>Properties(N)>Display>Toggle Grid Floor(On/Off).Also the "Only Render" option available in the same panel ,can be used to see the render without objects like grid, camera ,lights etc